# Each word of Torah is its own mitzvah for gentiles?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study, mitzvah, torah-reading, reward-punishment

This is a quote from an article I read on torchweb.org

"The Vilna Gaon in Shenos Eliyahu explains that **each and every word of Torah that we study is its own separate mitzvah with its own separate Divine reward**, unlike with other mitzvos where we only receive one Divine reward for each act of mitzvah performed.

This means that if we study Torah for one hour we will potentially have “racked up” hundreds of mitzvos!!" Source:https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=464

Okay so my question is: **Do gentiles recieve these same rewards for reading Torah (as stated above) as Jews do?** Do they recieve any spiritual reward at all?

P.s. This is from thelehrhaus.com

The merits of Talmud Torah

1 Mitzvah- Each Letter

4 Mitzvah- Average word

Average Word 4*613, Talmud Torah= All Mitzvos (Vilna Gaon- Every word learned is equal to all of the mitzvos) = 2,452 Mitzvos!

1 minute one can say 200 words= 2,452*200= 490,400 mitzvos!

1 hour of continuous learning= 29,424,000 mitzvos!

Learning with simcha (Orchat Tzadikim writes- any mitzvah done with simcha is multiplied 1,000 times) 29,424,000,000 mitzvos!

Learning by pushing oneself-multiplies the mitzvah 100 times 2,942,400,000,000 mitzvos! (אבות דר' נתן)

Learning with a Chevrusa (causing another person to learn) multiply amount of people you learn with....

Learning in Eretz Yisrael multiply by 2 (brought down in sefer ויואל משה)

Source: [https://thelehrhaus.com/timely-thoughts/rack-up-those-mitzvot/#:~:text=Each%20letter%20of%20Torah%20is,490%2C400%20mitzvot%20in%20a%20minute](https://thelehrhaus.com/timely-thoughts/rack-up-those-mitzvot/#:%7E:text=Each%20letter%20of%20Torah%20is,490%2C400%20mitzvot%20in%20a%20minute)

Comment: Note that [Mishneh Torah Melachim uMilchamot 10:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-10.htm#v9) says (in translation): "A gentile who studies the Torah is obligated to die. They should only be involved in the study of their seven mitzvot... If a gentile studies the Torah... a Jewish court should beat him, punish him, and inform him that he is obligated to die. However, he is not to be executed." See also [other] [questions tagged both 'gentiles' and 'torah-study'](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentiles+torah-study).

Comment: Another way of looking at the point raised by @TamirEvan is that for Jewish men, Torah study is a mitzvah in itself, independent of what "practical" results, if any, it yields (for example, studying opinions not accepted as halachah is also a mitzvah). For Jewish women and for non-Jews, by contrast, Torah study is only a means to an end - to know what to do and what not to do - and so there's not necessarily spiritual value and reward for each letter.